# Why development server doesn't open on new tab when I run 'npm start' in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am quite new to react-native and was following youtube tutorial for learning purposes. I have created basic react-native app with `expo init FirstProject`. Everything is working fine but when I run `npm start`, development server does not open on new tab. In every tutorial when `npm start` is run, it starts development server like this [development server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFXeG.png). Thats not case for me, I have tried several solutions but none has worked me. I haven't changed any file at all, so I hope there is no purpose of sharing my App.js as it is default. I don't get any errors, but still development server doesn't open in new tab. This is what I get: [My terminal after I run npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kISFU.png). Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web UI is no longer part of the expo-cli, it was removed in version 6.0.0. You are most likely watching tutorials that are using versions prior to that release.

If you would like to read more, here is the official post from Expo: https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206.